# Proving a bi-conditional predicate calculus formulae

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Prove the following:

```
∀x(C → D(x)) ↔ (C →∀xD(x))
```

I am looking at the axioms I can use under hilberts deductive system as well as the Generalization rule but I can't find an axiom that supports the biconditional connective. any help?

Comment: Prove two statements. First $\to$ and then $\leftarrow$

Comment: I have done that but now I have hit a brick wall. I can't seem to prove the first part. Any insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to prove that, if $x$ does not occur free in $C$, then

> $\vdash (C → ∀xD(x)) ↔ ∀x(C → D(x))$.

---

---

A) To prove :

> $\vdash (C → ∀xD(x)) → ∀x(C → D(x))$.

1) $C → ∀xD(x)$ --- assumed

2) $C$ --- assumed

3) $∀xD(x)$ --- from 1) and 2) by *modus ponens*

4) $D(x)$ --- from 3) and Axiom.1 : $∀x \alpha → \alpha _t^x$, by *mp*

5) $C → D(x)$ --- from 2) and 4) by **Deduction Th**

6) $∀x(C → D(x))$ --- from 5) by **Generalization Th** : $x$ is not free in assumption 1)

> 7) $(C → ∀xD(x)) \rightarrow ∀x(C → D(x))$ --- from 1) and 6) by **Deduction Th**

---

B) To prove :

> $\vdash ∀x(C → D(x)) → (C → ∀xD(x))$.

1) $∀x(C → D(x))$ --- assumed

2) $C$ --- assumed

3) $C → D(x)$ --- from 1) and Axiom.1 by *mp*

4) $D(x)$ --- from 2) and 3) by *mp*

5) $∀x D(x)$ --- from 4)  by **Generalization Th** : $x$ is not free in assumptions 1) and 2)

6)  $C → ∀x D(x)$ --- from 2) and 5) by **Deduction Th**

> 7) $∀x(C → D(x)) → (C → ∀x D(x))$ --- from 1) and 6) by **Deduction Th**

---

The theorem follows from A) and B) by *tautological implication* :

> > $\alpha \rightarrow \beta, \beta \rightarrow \alpha \vDash \alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$